# Is $\sum_{n,m \in \mathbb Z^2} e^{-\Vert n-m \Vert} \frac{1}{1+\Vert n \Vert^{1+\varepsilon}} \frac{1}{1+\Vert m \Vert^{1+\varepsilon}}$ summable?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

I would like to ask whether the expression

$$\sum_{n,m \in \mathbb Z^2} e^{-\Vert n-m \Vert} \frac{1}{1+\Vert n \Vert^{1+\varepsilon}} \frac{1}{1+\Vert m \Vert^{1+\varepsilon}}$$

is finite?

Intuitively, this should be the case as away from the diagonal $n=m$ the exponential is rapidly decaying and on the diagonal, this expression is summable, but I cannot make it rigorous.

EDIT: The sum is over $n$ and $m$ both in $\mathbb Z^2.$

Comment: Can we please clarify: Do you mean that each of $n$ and $m$ is a vector in $\mathbb Z^2$? Or do you mean $(n ,m) \in \mathbb Z^2$?

Comment: sorry, it is indeed that both $n$ amd $m$ are in $\mathbb Z^2.$

Comment: okay, I'll delete my ealier answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note first that everything is positive.

Then

$$\sum_{n,m \in \mathbb Z^2} e^{-\Vert n-m \Vert} \frac{1}{1+\Vert n \Vert^{1+\varepsilon}} \frac{1}{1+\Vert m \Vert^{1+\varepsilon}} \stackrel{m-n=k}{===}\sum_{k \in \mathbb Z^2}\sum_{m \in \mathbb Z^2} e^{-\Vert k \Vert} \frac{1}{1+\Vert m+k \Vert^{1+\varepsilon}} \frac{1}{1+\Vert m \Vert^{1+\varepsilon}} \\\stackrel{m-n=k}{===}\sum_{k \in \mathbb Z^2}e^{-\Vert k \Vert} \sum_{m \in \mathbb Z^2} \frac{1}{1+\Vert m+k \Vert^{1+\varepsilon}} \frac{1}{1+\Vert m \Vert^{1+\varepsilon}} $$

Now, for each $k \in \mathbb Z^2$ you have by Cauchy- Schwartz (you have to prove this step by looking at the partial sums)

$$\left(\sum_{m \in \mathbb Z^2} \frac{1}{1+\Vert m \Vert^{1+\varepsilon}} \frac{1}{1+\Vert m+k \Vert^{1+\varepsilon}} \right)^2 \leq  \left( \sum_{m \in \mathbb Z^2} \frac{1}{(1+\Vert m\Vert^{1+\varepsilon})^2} \right)\left( \sum_{m \in \mathbb Z^2} \frac{1}{(1+\Vert m+k\Vert^{1+\varepsilon})^2} \right)\\=\left( \sum_{m \in \mathbb Z^2} \frac{1}{(1+\Vert m\Vert^{1+\varepsilon})^2} \right)^2 $$

Now, it is easy to argue that 
$$C:= \left( \sum_{m \in \mathbb Z^2} \frac{1}{(1+\Vert m\Vert^{1+\varepsilon})^2} \right)< \infty$$

Therefore,
$$\sum_{n,m \in \mathbb Z^2} e^{-\Vert n-m \Vert} \frac{1}{1+\Vert n \Vert^{1+\varepsilon}} \frac{1}{1+\Vert m \Vert^{1+\varepsilon}} \leq \sum_{k \in \mathbb Z^2}e^{-\Vert k \Vert} \cdot C <\infty  $$

Comment: thank you very much for your help, it is a wonderful answer.